# Checking for execute permission with Java 1.5

Tags: java

I'm looking for a way to check if a file is executable with Java 1.5.

I found [SecurityManager.checkExec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html#checkExec%28java.lang.String%29) but I don't think it helps...

I'm currently on Linux, but this needs to work for Windows also.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Java SE 7 before Posix attributes are part of the Java library (`java.nio.file`). Otherwise, you'll need to exec a process or use JNI (possibly from someone else's library).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SecurityManager.checkExec` actually checks something else, it checks whether your JVM has sufficent permissions to launch an executable.

You want `java.nio.file.Files.isExecutable(...)` to see if the file is considered "executable".

It is available only in Java 1.7.  For 1.5 and later, you would typically construct a `ProcessBuilder` class and and capture exceptions on failure to execute the file.  For prior to 1.5, you would use the `Runtime.exec(...)` and capture the exception to determine that the file wasn't executable.

Comment: I'm not looking to actually execute the file, I'm just trying to distinguish between a file they can read from, and something they'd actually want to run.

Comment: @Dsynomic The concept of "Executable" isn't the same in differing operating systems.  You could upgrade to Java 1.7 to get a polymoric file system sub-system which handles the details on a platform-matching basis, or you can write an interface, a per-platform construction block, and multiple per-platform solutions to check executable-ness.  There's not an out-of-the-box solution for Java 1.5.  That's why people typically "tried" to execute to see if it was executable.

Comment: Alright, I think I can write a temporary solution that will do what I want until I can upgrade to Java 1.7.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem.

If you don't mind doing a lot of work, you can try and reading the "magic numbers" for the executable files. These are the values stored in the beginning of files that can tell you what kind of file it is.

Take a look at http://www.garykessler.net/library/magic.html which has a huge list of the "magic numbers" for various file formats, including executables.

It shouldn't be that hard if you just need to do it on two platforms.

If anyone can tell me why this is a really bad idea, I'd be interested.